# How To save output in python

Tags: python

I have a problem with this line

```
    print(Fore.RED+'NOT Found: '+url ,file=open('output.txt','w'))
```

I need to save the request to this output but it's not working

```
res = requests.get(url)
        if payload in res.text:
           print(Fore.GREEN +'Found   -->','   ' , f"{url}" + Fore.RESET)
           
        else :
            print(Fore.RED+'XSS NOT Found: '+url ,file=open('output.txt','w'))
```

Comment: what is the error message you get

Comment: just save one line  if i have 1000 line the output saved one line

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is,

```
file=open('output.txt','w')
```

you use "w" parameter in your function."w" parameter deletes post information and overwrites current information all the time.
If you want to append data to file, you should use

```
file=open('output.txt','a')
```

Comment: thank you I searched on the internet for 1 day I can't find this problem
thank you it's done

Comment: how ? I'm new here?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

this?

Comment: ok, it's because you're new  .Forget about it

Comment: thank you if i got rep i will back an I give you